Apple Metal screen tearing
I'm trying to setup a project for learning real-time rendering techniques with apple metal (I'm on a macbook air m1), but I'm facing issues that I don't understand.
I'm using SDL2 and metal-cpp, and I could set up a base project that clears and renders a triangle, however if I disable vsync there is a huge tearing problem; the fact is that if I use opengl this does not happen and there is no tearing regardless vsync.
Another issue is that if I enable VSync, when i try to move the window there is a strong stutter before the window starts moving, both with metal and OpenGL (and even with other window management libraries such as winit for Rust), but this does not happen if I make a Swift/Metal project with XCode.
I tried to setup a Swift/Metal project in XCode, but there are further behaviours that I can't understand: if I try to disable vsync fps stay capped at 60 and there is no tearing, but if I disable the presentWithTransaction option for the CAMetalLayer tearing happens, but fps still stay at 60.
Below the code for the SDL2 metal-cpp project.
Thanks in advance.
EDIT: I found a solution to the issue about the laggy movement of a SDL window with vsync enabled: https://github.com/rust-windowing/winit/issues/1737
The issue was caused by the app Magnet.
#include <iostream>
#include <imgui.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/Sdl_metal.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_render.h>
#include <simd/simd.h>

#define NS_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define CA_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define MTL_PRIVATE_IMPLEMENTATION
#include <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.hpp>
#include <Foundation/Foundation.hpp>
#include <Metal/Metal.hpp>

std::vector<simd::float3> get_triangle();

int main() {
    // DEVICE
    auto device = NS::TransferPtr(MTL::CreateSystemDefaultDevice());
    // COMMAND QUEUE
    auto commandQueue = NS::TransferPtr(device->newCommandQueue());
    
    if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_TIMER | SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
        SDL_Log("sdl init failed: %s", SDL_GetError());
    };
    
    // WINDOW
    auto window = SDL_CreateWindow(
                                   "Window",
                                   SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                   SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                                   400, 400,
                                   SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE | SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);
    if(!window) { SDL_Log("window creation failed: %s", SDL_GetError()); }
    
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_DRIVER, "metal");
    SDL_SetHint(SDL_HINT_RENDER_VSYNC, "0");
    auto renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);
    
    auto layer = (CA::MetalLayer*)SDL_RenderGetMetalLayer(renderer);
    if(!layer) { SDL_Log("failed to init metal layer: %s", SDL_GetError()); }
    
    layer->setPixelFormat(MTL::PixelFormatBGRA8Unorm);
    layer->setDevice(device.get());
    
    // set triangle buffer
    auto triangle = get_triangle();
    auto triangle_buffer = NS::TransferPtr(device->newBuffer(&triangle[0], triangle.size() * sizeof(simd::float3), MTL::ResourceStorageModeShared));
    
    // DEFAULT LIBRARY
    auto library = device->newDefaultLibrary();
    if(!library) { SDL_Log("failed to load default library"); std::exit(-1); }
    
    // RENDER PIPELINE
    auto vertexShader = library->newFunction(NS::String::string("vertexShader", NS::ASCIIStringEncoding));
    auto fragmentShader = library->newFunction(NS::String::string("fragmentShader", NS::ASCIIStringEncoding));
    auto renderPipelineDescriptor = MTL::RenderPipelineDescriptor::alloc()->init();
    renderPipelineDescriptor->setLabel(NS::String::string("triangle rendering", NS::ASCIIStringEncoding));
    renderPipelineDescriptor->setVertexFunction(vertexShader);
    renderPipelineDescriptor->setFragmentFunction(fragmentShader);
    vertexShader->release();
    fragmentShader->release();
    renderPipelineDescriptor->colorAttachments()->object(0)->setPixelFormat(layer->pixelFormat());
    NS::Error* err;
    auto renderPipelineState = device->newRenderPipelineState(renderPipelineDescriptor, &err);
    if(!renderPipelineState) { SDL_Log("render pipeline state creation failed"); std::exit(-1); }
    renderPipelineDescriptor->release();
    
    bool quit = false;
    SDL_Event event;
    while(!quit) {
        
        while(SDL_PollEvent(&event)) {
            if(event.type == SDL_QUIT) {
                quit = true;
            }
        }
        
        auto autoreleasePool = NS::TransferPtr(NS::AutoreleasePool::alloc()->init());
        
        auto commandBuffer = commandQueue->commandBuffer();
        auto drawable = layer->nextDrawable();
        
        // RENDER PASS DESCRIPTOR
        auto renderPassDescriptor = NS::TransferPtr(MTL::RenderPassDescriptor::alloc()->init());
        renderPassDescriptor->colorAttachments()->object(0)->setTexture(drawable->texture());
        renderPassDescriptor->colorAttachments()->object(0)->setLoadAction(MTL::LoadActionClear);
        renderPassDescriptor->colorAttachments()->object(0)->setClearColor(MTL::ClearColor(1, 0, 0, 1));
        renderPassDescriptor->colorAttachments()->object(0)->setStoreAction(MTL::StoreActionStore);
        
        // RENDER COMMAND ENCODER
        auto renderCommandEncoder = commandBuffer->renderCommandEncoder(renderPassDescriptor.get());
        renderCommandEncoder->setRenderPipelineState(renderPipelineState);
        renderCommandEncoder->setVertexBuffer(triangle_buffer.get(), 0, 0);
        renderCommandEncoder->drawPrimitives(MTL::PrimitiveTypeTriangle, NS::UInteger(0), NS::UInteger(3));
        
        renderCommandEncoder->popDebugGroup();
        renderCommandEncoder->endEncoding();
        
        commandBuffer->presentDrawable(drawable);
        commandBuffer->commit();
        commandBuffer->waitUntilCompleted();
    }
    
    SDL_DestroyWindow(window);
    SDL_Quit();
}

std::vector<simd::float3> get_triangle() {
    return std::vector<simd::float3>{
        simd::float3{-0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f},
        simd::float3{ 0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f},
        simd::float3{ 0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f}
    };
}

